# How do I share VPN (PPTP) connection via WIFI adapter as hotspot?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn

I'm pretty new to Linux and what I'am trying to achieve is to use my OrangePi PC to act as a hotspot in my house.
I want to use WIFI adapter to share my internet VPN (PPTP) connection.
So far I have successfully connected OrangePi to PPTP and internet worked when I tried to set my WIFI adapter as a hotspot via Network-manager.My phone was successfully connected to wireless network I shared over WIFI adapter but there was no Internet.I think that hotspot I created shares wrong network (eth0) instead of (ppp0)
How do I fix that? Thanks